# Array like object with data-attribute used as the key?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have items on my page like this:

```
<audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
```

I need to play the audio item when a function is called and the variable passed is the same value as the data-key.

So when 65 is passed then this will work:

```
const sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'); 

const makeSound = function() {
    sounds[0].play();
}
```

However that solution is obviously not scalable. Is there a way I can make an array like object where the key is the audio item's data-key? I so I think I want an object like this:

```
arrayLikeObj = [
    {
        65,
        <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
    },
    {
        83,
        <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
    },
    {
        68,
        <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
    }
 ]


const makeSound = function(soundNo) {
    sounds[soundNo].play();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make it an object, with keys as `data-key`?

Comment: What is `soundNo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'); 
const map = arr => fn => Array.prototype.map.call(arr, fn)

const r = map(sounds)(s => Object.assign({[s.dataset.key]: s }))
  .reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, c), {})

console.log(r)
```

```html
<audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
```

Usage:

```
const makeSound = function(soundNo) {
    r[soundNo].play();
}

makeSound(83)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are objects, but `arrayLikeObj` is not an array-like object: it is a regular array!

In fact, `arrayLikeObj` is an array of (invalid) object literals. As [wostex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7636961/wostex) pointed out, I suspect you want the following data structure:

```
{
  65: <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>,
  83: <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>,
  68: <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
}
```

*Note that this is not an array-like object either because it does not have a `length` property*.

To get this data structure, you could use a `for...of` loop:

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'),
    sounds = {};

for (const audio of elements) {
  sounds[audio.getAttribute('data-key')] = audio;
}

const makeSound = function (soundNo) {
  sounds[soundNo].play();
}

console.log(sounds);

makeSound(65); // <--- Try to change the number and run the script again...
```

```html
<audio data-key="65" src="https://www.gnu.org/music/FreeSWSong.ogg"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="https://www.gnu.org/music/free-software-song-herzog.ogg"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="https://www.gnu.org/music/free-software-song-rhythmic.ogg"></audio>
```

Feel free to play with the snippet ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7002bwj/)). It is working fine, at least on Firefox where Ogg is supported... On Stack Overflow, you can "Hide results" if you want to stop music.